# Can't control Turtle from tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make turtle graphics which can be controlled from `tkinter`. Everything works fine except one thing:`enter code here` Every time when I type numbers in entry widgets and click button it doesn't work (doesn't draw).

Please help me if you can.

Here's code:

```
import turtle
from tkinter import*
from random import*

def colorred():
    turtle.color("red")

def colorblue():
    turtle.color("blue")

def colororange():
    turtle.color("orange")

def coloryellow():
    turtle.color("yellow")

def turtleshape():
    shapes=["arrow",'turtle', 'circle', 'square', 'triangle', 'classic']
    i=randint(0,5)
    turtle.shape(shapes[int(i)])


'''arrow', 'turtle', 'circle', 'square', 'triangle', 'classic'.'''

root=Tk()
root.title("palindrome checker")
frame=Frame(root)
frame.pack()
ekr=turtle.Screen()
turtle.tiltangle(90)
inp1=IntVar()
inp2=IntVar()
inp3=IntVar()
leng1=inp1.get()
leng=inp2.get()
rad=inp3.get()


def square(distance):
    print("clicked")
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.left(5)

def triangel(length):
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(240)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(240)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(60)
    turtle.left(5)

def circle(radius):
    turtle.circle(radius)
    turtle.left(5)

red=Button(frame,bg="red",fg="red",width=8,command=colorred)
red.grid(row=1,column=0)

blue=Button(frame,bg="blue",fg="blue",width=8,command=colorblue)
blue.grid(row=1,column=1)

DRAW=Button(frame,bg="white",fg="green",text="SHAPE",width=8,command=turtleshape)
DRAW.grid(row=1,column=2)

orange=Button(frame,bg="orange",fg="orange",width=8,command=colororange)
orange.grid(row=1,column=3)

yellow=Button(frame,bg="yellow",fg="yellow",width=8,command=coloryellow)
yellow.grid(row=1,column=4)


square=Button(frame,text="square",bg="white",fg="black",width=6,bd=4,command=square(leng1))
square.grid(row=2,column=1)

lab1=Label(frame,text="length-->")
lab1.grid(row=2,column=2)

disp1=Entry(frame,textvariable=inp1,width=6,bd=4)
disp1.grid(row=2,column=3)

triangle=Button(frame,text="triangle",bg="white",fg="black",width=6,bd=4,command=triangel(leng))
triangle.grid(row=3,column=1)

lab2=Label(frame,text="length-->")
lab2.grid(row=3,column=2)

disp2=Entry(frame,textvariable=inp2,width=6,bd=4)
disp2.grid(row=3,column=3)

circle=Button(frame,text="circle",bg="white",fg="black",width=6,bd=4,command=circle(rad))
circle.grid(row=4,column=1)

lab3=Label(frame,text="radius-->")
lab3.grid(row=4,column=2)

disp3=Entry(frame,textvariable=inp3,width=6,bd=4)
disp3.grid(row=4,column=3)


turtle.listen(15,15)
mainloop()
```

Comment: For starters...turtle.color("red") should be indented according to the same standard that you used for your control structure.  Maybe two spaces?  I recommend four but that is a lot more work.  That indention has to apply evenly across all of your program

Comment: Click what `Button`? What doesn't draw? Please create a MCVE demonstrating the problem. See [_How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to pass the function to the callback (not it's return value) you should use:

```
mysquare=Button(frame,text="square",bg="white",fg="black",width=6,bd=4,command=square)
```

Also there is no need to pass parameters to the callback functions, you can use:

```
distance=int(disp1.get())
```

So the code should look like:

```
import turtle
from tkinter import *
from random import *


def colorred():
    turtle.color("red")


def colorblue():
    turtle.color("blue")


def colororange():
    turtle.color("orange")


def coloryellow():
    turtle.color("yellow")


def turtleshape():
    shapes = ["arrow", 'turtle', 'circle', 'square', 'triangle', 'classic']
    i = randint(0, 5)
    turtle.shape(shapes[int(i)])


'''arrow', 'turtle', 'circle', 'square', 'triangle', 'classic'.'''

root = Tk()
root.title("palindrome checker")
frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack()
ekr = turtle.Screen()
turtle.tiltangle(90)
inp1 = IntVar()
inp2 = IntVar()
inp3 = IntVar()
leng1 = inp1.get()
leng = inp2.get()
rad = inp3.get()


def square():
    print("clicked")
    distance = int(disp1.get())
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.forward(distance)
    turtle.left(90)
    turtle.left(5)


def triangel():
    length = int(disp2.get())
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(240)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(240)
    turtle.forward(length)
    turtle.left(60)
    turtle.left(5)


def circle():
    radius = int(disp3.get())
    turtle.circle(radius)
    turtle.left(5)


red = Button(frame, bg="red", fg="red", width=8, command=colorred)
red.grid(row=1, column=0)
blue = Button(frame, bg="blue", fg="blue", width=8, command=colorblue)
blue.grid(row=1, column=1)
DRAW = Button(frame, bg="white", fg="green", text="SHAPE", width=8, command=turtleshape)
DRAW.grid(row=1, column=2)
orange = Button(frame, bg="orange", fg="orange", width=8, command=colororange)
orange.grid(row=1, column=3)
yellow = Button(frame, bg="yellow", fg="yellow", width=8, command=coloryellow)
yellow.grid(row=1, column=4)

mysquare = Button(frame, text="square", bg="white", fg="black", width=6, bd=4, command=square)
mysquare.grid(row=2, column=1)
lab1 = Label(frame, text="length-->")
lab1.grid(row=2, column=2)
disp1 = Entry(frame, textvariable=inp1, width=6, bd=4)
disp1.grid(row=2, column=3)
triangle = Button(frame, text="triangle", bg="white", fg="black", width=6, bd=4, command=triangel)
triangle.grid(row=3, column=1)
lab2 = Label(frame, text="length-->")
lab2.grid(row=3, column=2)
disp2 = Entry(frame, textvariable=inp2, width=6, bd=4)
disp2.grid(row=3, column=3)
circle = Button(frame, text="circle", bg="white", fg="black", width=6, bd=4, command=circle)
circle.grid(row=4, column=1)
lab3 = Label(frame, text="radius-->")
lab3.grid(row=4, column=2)
disp3 = Entry(frame, textvariable=inp3, width=6, bd=4)
disp3.grid(row=4, column=3)

turtle.listen(15, 15)
mainloop()
```